# prove that a is of order m if and only if $a^m = e$ and $a^k $is not $e$ for all $0 < k < m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

$a$ is of order $m$ if and only if $a^m = e$ and $a^k \neq e$ for all $0 < k < m$.

It is about order in Algebra. I sketch the proof. Is it correct? I need your help.

First ($\Rightarrow$)
Let $| \langle a\rangle | = m$, then $\langle a\rangle = \{e, a, a^2, a^3, \cdots , a^{m-2}, a^{m-1} \}$
Since $| \langle a \rangle | = m$, $a^i$ is not equal to $a^j$ for $0 < i, j < m$
If $a^m$ is not equal to e, then $a^k = a^m$ for $0 < k < m$. because $| \langle a \rangle | = m$.
So $a^{m-k} = e$. and it is contradiction that $| \langle a \rangle | = m$.
therefore $a^m = e$. and
If $a^k = e$ for $0 < k < m$. then $| \langle a \rangle |$ is not equal to $m$. 
So $a^k$ is not equal to $e$ for $0 < k < m$.

($\Leftarrow$)
For $0 < i, j < m\; (i > j)$, if $a^i = a^j$, then $a^(i-j) = e$.
But since $a^m = e$, $(i - j) = m$. It is contradiction to $0 < i, j < m$.
Therefore $a^i$ is not equal to $a^j$ and number of $a^k$ for $0 < k < m$ is $(m - 1)$.
So $| \langle a \rangle | = (m - 1) + 1 = m$ ($a^m = e$ is one).

Comment: Both directions trivially follow from the definition of order of a an element of a group, there isn't anything to prove. In fact this is the definition, just with an iff thrown in.

Comment: @tom From the way the question is posed I'm guessing the OP's definition of the order of an element is the size of the subgroup it generates as opposed to the least exponent which makes it 1. In that case while the proof is certainly not hard I wouldn't say there is nothing to prove. For example if instead of a group you have a non-associative structure I would guess the two definitions don't have to coincide.

Comment: Fair enough, yeah I guess your proof looks fine in that case then.

Comment: @DRF umm sorry about that i do not write some condition. G is a group and a is in G

Comment: @Tom I know that it is also definition. but I know how to prove it. Really is my writing fine??

Comment: In fact in the backwards direction you say that $a^{i-j}=e$ implies $i-j=m$ which is not true but you know $0<i-j<m$ so this immediately contradicts your assumption.

Comment: @Tom Right i know it now. thanks